# How to concatenate two vectors of different dimensions

Tags: python, tensorflow

If X = [[ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]] and Y = [[ 0.  0.  0.  0.]] - how can I concatenate the two vectors to form a single vector along column?

I did the following but it didn't work:

```
import tensorflow as tf
X = tf.constant(1.0, shape=[1, 6])
Y = tf.zeros(shape=[1,4])
XY = tf.concat((X,Y), axis = 0)
sess = tf.Session()
print(sess.run(XY))
```

Comment: Do you mean obtaining a vector of shape `[1, 10]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to concat them on axis 0, then their size must be equal

Assuming that you don't want it,

you need to set `axis = 1` in the `tf.concat` method